# Moq - It.Is without having to specify all properties

Tags: c#, moq

I'm using Moq to test a method, and the method under test takes a json string as an argument, deserialises this into the expected class object, and calls a service with this deserialised class object.

I want to setup my service to expect an instance of the class object in question with the correct values, so that I can verify the step to deserialise the json string to class object works as expected.

Currently, I'm using the `It.Is<MyClass>(...)` method, however this means that I have to specify *every* property, and some of the expected objects contain *a lot* of properties.

```
public class MyClassTests
{
    private Mock<IMyService> _serviceMock = new Mock<IMyService>();

    public void UnitTest01()
    {
        // Arrange
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject
        {
            SomeProperty01 = "One",
            SomeProperty02 = 2,
            Timestamp = DateTime.Now
        };

        string input = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);

        // *** how can I improve this so I dont have to specify every property? ***

        _serviceMock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.Is<MyObject>(o =>
            o.SomeProperty01 == myObject.SomeProperty01
            && o.SomeProperty02 == myObject.SomeProperty02
            && o.Timestamp == myObject.Timestamp
            )));

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(_serviceMock.Object);

        // Act
        myClass.DoWork(input);

        // Assert
        _serviceMock.Verify();
    }
}

// The class under test
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;

    public MyClass(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    // The method under test. I want to verify that deserialising works as expected, 
    // and that the service is called with the expected argument.
    public void DoWork(string jsonString)
    {
        MyObject deserialised = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonString);

        _myService.DoSomething(deserialised);
    }
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void DoSomething(MyObject myObject)
    {
        // For the sake of this test, it doesnt matter what this service method does
    }
}

public interface IMyService
{
    void DoSomething(MyObject myObject);
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string SomeProperty01 { get; set; }
    public int SomeProperty02 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    // Loads more properties...
}
```

Is it possible to do something similar to `It.Is<MyObject>()` where I dont have to specify each property? One solution might be to overrride the MyObject.Equals method, i.e. `It.Is<MyObject>(o => o.Equal(myObject))`. However, this is't ideal as it involves changing code for the sake of unit tests.

Comment: Is `mock.SetupAllProperties();` helpful for you, have you tried? It setups stubs for all properties, do exact values important for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing the approach. Capture the passed argument in a `Callback` from the mock and then assert that it is as expected using [FluentAssertions](https://fluentassertions.com/).

```
public class MyClassTests {
    private Mock<IMyService> _serviceMock = new Mock<IMyService>();

    public void UnitTest01() {
        // Arrange
        MyObject expected = new MyObject {
            SomeProperty01 = "One",
            SomeProperty02 = 2,
            Timestamp = DateTime.Now
        };

        MyObject actual = null;

        //Setup the mock to capture the passed argument in a callback
        _serviceMock
            .Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<MyObject>())
            .Callback(MyObject arg => { actual = arg; });

        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(_serviceMock.Object);
        string input = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expected);

        // Act
        myClass.DoWork(input);

        // Assert using FluentAssertions
        actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
    }
}
```

Now the test can be exercised without having to change the subject under test.

Comment: Brilliant! I was hoping someone was going to point out that there was some hidden `It.IsEquivalentTo()` method in Moq, but this approach works great. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KellermanSoftware.CompareNetObjects library and create an extension method for objects like this:

```
    public static bool IsEqual<T>(this T value, T other, ComparisonConfig config = null)
    {
        var comparer = new CompareLogic();
        if (config != null) comparer.Config = config;

        var comparisonResult = comparer.Compare(value, other);

        return comparisonResult.AreEqual;
    }
```

Then you can use:

`_serviceMock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.Is<MyObject>(o =>
            o.IsEqual(myObject)));`